# Install module with pip command in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to install BeautifulSoup library for HTML parsing. I try to use the pip command. I have completed the preliminaries. I add C:\Python27; in the PATH. I ran it typing python and import pip. It's all ok.I type

```
>>>pip install beautifulsoup4
      File "<stdin>", line 1
        pip install beautifulsoup4
                  ^
>>>python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
      File "<stdin>", line 1
        python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
                    ^
```

What step do I miss? I cannot figure out. [The site of the library.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: `pip` is a package manager, so you install the package with it, not use it as an import.

Comment: This very same question been asked three times already this morning...

Comment: Try running the command from your `terminal`, not your `Python IDLE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ela re Θανάση it's easy :
`cd C:\Python27\Scripts`
`pip install beautifulsoup4`

Answer (score 1):

`pip` should be executed from your *OS* shell, not from a Python shell. E.g.

```
C:\>python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or

```
you@machine$ python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

You may also be able to just run `pip` directly instead of `python -m pip`.

Comment: @abccd, sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Your first example should be `C:\>py -3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4` since `python` isn't a default command in Windows.

Comment: @abccd, are you saying that there's a `py` binary installed by default on Windows? I don't think so, but I haven't used Windows in quite some time. In any case, the question specifies that the OP added the Python directory to `%PATH%` and was able to run Python with `python`.

Comment: Well, it's all good since that dir is added to %PATH%. If it's not, `py` is the valid command while `python` does not exist

Answer (score 1):

pip is it's own command, not run from the python interpreter.